# Using Rodriguez to prove Legendre

Tags: special-functions, legendre-polynomials

Trying to prove that: $$\int_{-1}^1 P_n(x)P_k(x)\,dx=\frac{-1}{2^nn!} \int_{-1}^1 P_k'(x) \frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n+1}}(x^2-1)^n \,dx$$

I know that by the Rodriguez formula, $$P_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^nn!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n$$

Would I just plug Rodriguez into the original integral? I tried that and have gotten to: $$\frac{1}{2^nn!}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^nP_k(x)\,dx$$

Any pointers on how to go about this?

Comment: Use integration by parts to move one derivative from $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n$ over to $P_k(x)$.

Comment: Well that explains why I'm having trouble. I know integration by parts for basic calculus but at this level I am stumped. How do you do that for a nth derivative?

Comment: If we define $A = \frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}(x^2-1)^n$ then $\frac{dA}{dx} = \frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n$ so your integral can be written $\frac{1}{2^n n!}\int_{-1}^1 \frac{dA}{dx} P_k(x) {\rm d}x$

Comment: That makes perfect sense, Thank you! (Time for me to brush up on integration by parts)